# Joomla - can't embed custom javascript

Tags: javascript, plugins, joomla, jqtransform

- I have Joomla 1.5
- I have found a plugin for form styling, the "jqtransform"
- I have an article that imports a 'myform.php' page that connects to an external database

I try to embed the jquery plugin (the jqtransform) to stylize the form that resides in myform.php. The steps i make are:

- add link for the css in the header of joomla's index.php
- add the link for the jquery plugin inside joomla's index.php (or inside myform.php)
- add the class jqtransform in form tag of the myform.php (rquired by the plugin)
- at the end of the myform.php (or the joomla's index.php) i add the javascript snippet inside the script tags:

```
    $(function() {
           //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
           console.log("foo");
           $("form.jqtransform").jqTransform(); });
```

(needed for the plugin)

The problem is that the plugin doesn't work.

I debug the javascript inside the browser and put bookmark in front of `$(function(){});` and in front of `$("form.jqtransform").jqTransform(); });`

The first bookmark works ok (the browser halts).

The second bookmark doesn't do anything. That means the browser doesn't get inside the function.

The console log doesn't show anything.

Anyone has any idea??

Comment: use jQuery insted of $ symbol.Also you jQuery.noconflict; just above the script.Bcoz joomla default validation using mootools its make some conflict.It may solve your issue..

Comment: @JobinJose at the header where the js scripts are called there is the noconflict script that declares `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`. Should I use this declaration again before the snippet at the end of the page? Also should i use $j instead of jQuery? I tried some but didn't work out

Comment: @JobinJose I solved it. It was what you said. Can't you write it as an answer so as to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is JQuery Conflict.

You should use var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
Just above the script and use jq instead of $ symbol.
like:

```
 jq = jQuery.noConflict();
 jq(function(){});
 jq("form.jqtransform").jqTransform(); });
```

something like that.
Also you can add script from myform.php don't need to edit index.php for this kind of use.
Like a page required some js and css don't load it in the index.php
It will load everytime so speed will reduce.
For a component or module or specific page you can use joomla's default document factory.

Like:

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('your script file full path');
$document->addStylesheet('your style sheet full path ');
```

Hope this will help you friend..

Comment: I used the JFactory and the declaration of jqtransform and the css all went to the head. But now at debugging i have this `
    $j(function() {
        //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
        $j("form.jqtransform").jqTransform();
index.php:223TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$j("form.jqtransform").jqTransform()')
});
`. Any idea?

Comment: Well the problem is that the header the plugin is called first and then comes the jquery. I don't know how to change the order of these calls.

Comment: Try to include jquery file on top of the head include in index.php it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This method requires no editing to the template files.

Simply use a Custom HTML Module and Publish it in position

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("form.jqtransform").jqTransform(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: yes that could be an option too. But I think jobin jose is right. it is better to add the script in the custom php page. Also i think there is no need to create a record in database for a module that you are going to use only once.